# Actionbarsherlock setup in eclipse

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm finally getting around to using actionbarsherlock and every video / tutorial I see says to download the zip file and create a new project from existing source and select the Library folder ( this is where I fall down as there is no Library folder in this zip ) did something change or am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the "actionbarsherlock" folder, it is essentially the "Library" folder. Make sure once you start using ABS with your project that you maintain only one copy of the support v4 jar file